# How to ignore the header rows in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want my python script to automatically graph certain parts of a CSV file. I have managed to get the data I want by removing certain parts of the csv file through the .drop command, anyway the headers won't go away. I have used the header = none command. Please help someone!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv"
filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename="E:\Corona\csv\confirmedglobal/casesGlobal.csv")
print ("download file location: ", filename)
print ("download headers: ", headers)
print ("Download #1 Completed")


cases = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Corona\csv\confirmedglobal\casesGlobal.csv')   

cases.drop('Province/State', axis=1, inplace=True)
cases.drop('Country/Region', axis=1, inplace=True)
cases.drop('Lat', axis=1, inplace=True)
cases.drop('Long', axis=1, inplace=True)


cases.to_csv('E:\Corona\csv\confirmedglobal\casesGlobal.csv', header=None, index=True)


#Australian Capital
cases.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265] ,axis=0, inplace=True)

print(cases)
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is saved to the correct place? You missed the raw string indicator `r' '`after the `cases.to_csv` command.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `cases.to_csv('E:\Corona\csv\confirmedglobal\casesGlobal.csv', header=False, index=True)`
 instead `header=None`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Bruno but still getting the same problem, here is the output:   1/22/20  1/23/20  1/24/20  1/25/20  ...  5/25/20  5/26/20  5/27/20  5/28/20
8        0        0        0        0  ...      107      107      107      107

[1 rows x 128 columns]

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: The pandas version is 0.25.1

Comment: put the cases.to_csv('E:\Corona\csv\confirmedglobal\casesGlobal.csv', header=False, index=True) after cases.drop

than read the new csv file like this:
df = pd.read_csv(''E:\Corona\csv\confirmedglobal\casesGlobal.csv', header=None)

Comment: Yo that fixed everything. Thanks so much man, much appreciated :D